# HDMI output not detected in ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I was trying sound equalizer in ubuntu. Followed instructions to install qpaeq and edited some files. Something went wrong, I uninstalled it, and pulseaudio and restarted my system. After booting no sound output devices were available. Then followed few instructions to reinstall pulse-audio. I was able to get sound from laptop speakers but there is no option to select monitor speakers which was there.

I investigated a little and found out, while listing all sound cards from /proc/asound/cards, only PCH is being displayed. No HDMI sound card.

what should i do next?